# Sorting values in foot and inches in excel

Tags: excel

Is it possible to get Excel to read values in feet and inches?  And then sort?  In my industry, I use coordinates (X, Y) that are in foot and inch dimension form.  I export from a CAD program.  It exports with all of the X coordinates in one column (ex. [5'10"] or [ -3'3"] or [19'5"].....), and all of the Y coordinates in another column (also exported in foot and inch form)  Often there will be many corresponding coordinates in the X column that have the same value as in the Y column.  For layout purposes, I need to have my values sorted firstly by the Y column, and then sorted by the values in the X column, but the problem is Excel does not understand the true value of a value in foot and inch form, only how to sort alphabetically..

For engineering, construction, and architecture purposes, it would be great if excel could understand natively and sort values in the form of (Feet)'(Inches)"

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The easiest thing here would be to export with measurements in a single unit, e.g. export an inches only column.  That failing, you may generate such a column in Excel, though it would be more work.

Answer (score 0):

This should convert measurements in the format you show to inches:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("'",A1)-1)*12+IF(LEFT(A1)="-",-1,1)*SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("'",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),CHAR(34),"")
```

but assuming Tim's (and my) preferred option is not available I suspect I would apply Text to Columns, factor feet by 12 and add/subtract as appropriate.